# Tiny Green beetle

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I have some tiny, bright-green beetles on Granny Bonnet seed heads in Cornwall, UK. The insects have black heads and 3 black/yellow stripes across the back. They are ladybird shaped but much smaller. Any ideas what these might be?

Comment: I can’t help you personally, but I recommend trying the app Seek on the App Store. I find it to be very helpful and it probably could identify them. I recommend taking a picture and then going to images in the identification camera, it is much faster.

Comment: You could use an app and self-answer your question if you get a result, but I do think having a good quality picture will greatrly improve your chances of getting an answer here! See also https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the [nymph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nymph_(biology)) of some species of shield bug, such as the **Common Green Shieldbug** (*Palomena prasina*)

[image]

Source: [Wildlifeinsight.com](http://www.wildlifeinsight.com/galleries/british-insects/british-true-bugs/)

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_shield_bug):

> Green shield bugs are a very common shield bug throughout Europe, including Great Britain & Ireland, and are found in a large variety of habitats, including gardens.